# how to use PrintStream class to read and write to file?

Tags: java

I'm just trying to read data from one file and write it to the other. But everytime i try to use `ps.printf("%s", Filename);` to print the data in the "**Filname**" it just prints the actual name of the file instead of the data in it.

> **example**:
>
> inputfile name is visit.txt (typed in by the user)
>
> outputfile name is report.txt (typed in by the user)

`ps.printf("%s", Filename);` will print the word "visit.txt" into report.txt instead of printing the data that's in visit.txt

is PrintStream the wrong class to be reading data from a file?

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Veterinary {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String Filename;
    String Outputfilename;

    Scanner inputScanner = null;

    System.out.printf("Enter Your Input File Name: ");
    inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Filename = inputScanner.nextLine();

    //CREATES FILE READER
    inputScanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(Filename));
    System.out.printf("\n", Filename);

    System.out.printf("Enter Your Output File Name: ");


    PrintStream ps = null;

    inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Outputfilename = inputScanner.nextLine();

    try
    {
        ps = new PrintStream(Outputfilename);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR. Could not open file!");
    }

    ps.printf("%s", Filename);
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to use BufferedReader and BufferedWrite to read and write the input from the files.

Comment: why are you over-writing the variable with `inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);` - you have already opened the file `inputScanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(Filename));` - you may also want to loop over `inputScanner.nextLine();` until no more data

Comment: I would personally declare the Scanner on the same line that you instantiated it, there's no point in setting an initial null reference before its ever used

Comment: As I see, `FileName` means your input file and `OutputFileName` is your output file So, what you are asking to print is input file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after creating file reader, use the

```
Scanner inputScannerfile = new Scanner(new FileReader(Filename));
```

line instead of

```
inputScanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(Filename));
```

and in the last line

```
ps.printf("%s", inputScannerfile.nextLine());
```

problem with your code is that you scanned the input file but you didn't read the file
and in the last line you passed the inputfile name in `(ps.printf("%s",filename))` .That's why it is giving you the input file name.

Comment: Scanner inputScannerfile = new Scanner(new FileReader(Filename));

inputScanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(Filename));


The only difference i can see is that "Scanner" is now infront. How did that make it read the file?

Answer (score 0):

A PrintStream is for outputting a data. If you wish to read, then probably you can use InputStream.

One way to do it is:

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(
  new File("C:\users\Desktop\test.txt"));

byte[] buff = new byte[inputStream.available()];
inputStream.read(buff);

File target = new File("testTarget.txt");
OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(target);
outStream.write(buff);
```

Comment: This does not address the problem that the OP is having

Answer (score 0):

comment the line  `Outputfilename = inputScanner.nextLine();` 
and then replace line  `ps.printf("%s", Filename);` with following

```
while(inputScanner.hasNextLine()){
    ps.println(inputScanner.nextLine());
}
```

What wrong you are doning is you are writing `Filename` to the **printstream** which is a string value of your filename not the content in it.since you have opened a scanner for your input file you need to read each line from it and than add it to the prinstream of output file.and the reason why i commented line `Outputfilename = inputScanner.nextLine()`; is because it will read first line from input File  and then go to next line but we are not storing that to prinstream so if you dont comment that line then first line in your input file will not be wrtten into your output file.